# How to enable supported link by default using firebase dynamic link for Android 13

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

Recently I working on the firebase dynamic link , but I found out For android 13 , it wont prompt out the dialog box to let u choose open for mobile apps or browser, becausethe supported links is disable which is under the apps ( set as default > open supported links is disable) it will always redirect to browser instead of mobile apps, can I know any ideal how to  enable the open supported links as default so that I can redirect to mobile apps instead of web browser? [***Notes: For android 12 and below have no issue]

what have be done:

1. https://domain.name/.well-known/assetlinks.json , this assetlinks already done setup and validate good
2. by using this url :
   https://digitalassetlinks.googleapis.com/v1/statements:list?
   source.web.site=https://domain.name:optional_port&
   relation=delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls
   also verified good.

Can i know any workaround able to enable the supported links by default for android 13?

[image]

from the screenshoots I already set the autoVerify= true ,
for <data android:host name is the one I set in my firebase console for the  dynamic links  domain url.

Comment: Hi - Did you tried android:autoVerify="true" in intent-filter as after Android 12 it is necessary?

Comment: @MohammadMisbah, yes, already add  `android:autoVerify="true"`